# Mongoose 3.6+ population of populated fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to 3.6 release notes I should be able to populate the categories in my order.items.product docs but no go. Here's the schemas:

```
var Order = new Schema({
  items: [{
    product: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Product",
    }
      ...
  }]
});


var Product = new Schema({
  categories: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
  }]
});
```

My Query (one of many - I 've tried a few combos - this seems to be what is suggested)

```
Order.findById(id).populate('items.product').exec(function(err, doc) {
  var opts = {
    path: 'items.product.categories'
  };

  console.log(doc.items[0].product.categories) // [ 524f035de9d6178e460001a2, 524f0965e9d6178e460001b6 ] - these docs are in the database under the Category collection

  Order.populate(doc, opts, function(err, doc) {
    // Returns order with category array blank for each product
    console.log(doc.items[0].product.categories // []
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you accidentally typed `Order` again in your sub-population call.

The second populate call should be something like:

`Category.populate(doc, opts, function(err, doc) {...`

instead of

`Order.populate(doc, opts, function(err, doc) {...`

You're telling Mongoose to populate each Product's `Categories` array element as an `Order` instead of as a `Category`.

Comment: Funny that I actually had a typo but the one I was trying was Product. I thought I had tried Category but I must have had some other thing wrong when I tried it. This did the trick!